# Did this (while) loop cause emacs to crash?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

I needed to go through an XML file looking for certain tags whose contents were human-recognizable but not regex-recognizable and to work on those tags. I put together a keyboard macro that did the work I needed, then tried to use the following elisp to let me step through the file and just press <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd> for each tag instead of going back and forth between movement commands and macro executions.

```
(while t
  (progn
    (search-forward "<Name>")
    (move-beginning-of-line nil)
    (if (y-or-n-p "Problem? ")
        (call-last-kbd-macro)
      (next-line)
      )))
```

However, when I <kbd>M-:</kbd> evaluated this, it got to `y-or-n-p` and then emacs became unresponsive. I am using emacs on an OS X 10.7 machine. In Activity Monitor, emacs was taking up the normal amount of RAM and CPU time, not making escalating resource requests, so I don't think I ran into an infinite loop. Emacs simply stopped responding to typing and clicks altogether, including things like repeatedly hitting Escape or <kbd>C-g</kbd>. An additional detail: the one `y-or-n-p` interaction I got was a dialog box, not in the minibuffer, which was strange - I clicked Yes on it and the dialog box went away, which was the last interaction I was able to get with emacs before it disappeared into deep space.

Is there something in the above elisp code that's inherently dangerous? My thought was that the `(search-forward)` would fail at the end of the buffer, signal an error, and the loop would end.

Comment: I'm curious to know what about the information you are seeking is not regex recognizable?.

Comment: It amounted to "does this look funny?" and unless I missed something in recent Perl versions no-one has a regex for "looks funny". :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this so that the search fails the loop terminates. This code could still loop forever if the call-last-kbd-macro moves point back before the previous search.

```
(while (search-forward "<Name>" nil t)
  (progn
    (move-beginning-of-line nil)
    (if (y-or-n-p "Problem? ")
        (call-last-kbd-macro)
      (next-line))))
```

Comment: So you're thinking that `(while t)` could have caused a problem and it'd be better to explicit make the search the condition of the while-loop?

Comment: Yeah, nothing will terminate the loop with your original code.

Comment: Okay, that comment and your answer, combined, tell me what I wanted to know, so I'm accepting this. :)